# Make text indent flat like ordered list with css

Tags: html, css

i want to make my FAQ Q & A will act flat like ordered list, is there any idea to make it possible

http://i57.tinypic.com/2uff5uq.jpg

```
<div class="col-left">
<h3><strong>CAPTION</strong></h3>
<ul>
<li>Q: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.</li>
<li>A: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.</li>
<li>Q: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.</li>
<li>A: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.:</li>
</ul>

<ol start="1">
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.!</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.</li>
<li>Anda akan diminta untuk melengkapi Informasi Tagihan lalu pilih Jasa Pengiriman yang Anda inginkan.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.</li>
</ol>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a better description of what you're trying to achieve? Please put your code here so we can help. A jsfiddle.net would also help.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2uff5uq&s=8#.U1jtwfldXTc

Comment: i need my ul li for q & a style is same with the ordered list, the left indent is flat @Daze

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRc2Z/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Question</li>
    <li>Answer
        <ol>
            <li>Answer 1</li>
            <li>Answer 2</li>
            <li>Answer 3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
ul> li:nth-child(1):before {
    content:'Q:';
}
ul> li:nth-child(2):before {
    content:'A:';
}
li {
    margin:20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
    text-indent: -1.25rem;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsPUJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that a definition list might be more appropriate in this case:

```
<dl class="faq">
    <dt>the question.</dt>
    <dd>the answer
        <ol>
            <li>if answer contains a list, first item in list.</li>
            <li>if answer contains a list, second item in list.</li>
        </ol>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

You would then style with generated content to label question and answers, and adjust the margins as you like:

```
.faq {margin-left: 1.5em;}
.faq dd {margin-top: 1em; margin-left: 0;}
.faq dt:before {
    content: "Q. ";
    margin-left: -1.25em;
}
.faq dd:before {
    content: "A. ";
    margin-left: -1.25em;
}
```

Se demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsLpL/